# Run Databricks (Spark) Locally Using Docker Image

Tags: docker, databricks

I want to run databaricks/spark container locally. I've found an image below:
https://github.com/databricks/containers

I've pulled it and run it. Docker ran successfully but I cannot figure out how to start cluster or launch UI or Notebook.

I've used standard image as it should have python notebooks:
https://github.com/databricks/containers/tree/master/ubuntu/standard

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First off, Databricks is more than Spark. Do you want to run Databricks or Spark ?

Databricks cannot be run on local docker containers. What you can do is to create a customer docker [image](https://docs.databricks.com/clusters/custom-containers.html) with databricks code and then run it in cloud.

However, you may want to run jupyter pyspark-notebook in [docker](https://hub.docker.com/r/jupyter/pyspark-notebook)

Answer (score -1):

Try pointing your browser to `localhost:8888`. You might also need to configure port-forwarding for the container.